# Changing color of a specific point in a mapbox layer

Tags: filtering, mapbox-gl-js

Is there a way in mapbox-gl-js to select a specific point in a mapbox layer and change its paint property while keeping all the other points in the layer unchanged (ie grey) ?

For instance, imagine that each point in the (single) layer in the map have up to 40 properties A1,A2,..... A40.

I want to color as red all the points where A1=1, as blue all the points where A2=1 etc.... Points where all the columns A1... A40 equal to 0, stay to the default color gray. No point can have more than a 1 in the row A1... A40.

Is this possible to do this without creating 40 different layers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give different colors to marker circle in mapbox gl js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394404/how-to-give-different-colors-to-marker-circle-in-mapbox-gl-js)